# Extract required text from Word document using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

Can anyone tell me how to extract only required text from Word document using C#.

**About Word document:**

Word document contains some simple text and audio text and I want to differentiate and extract that text from word doc into excel.

Storyboard [Screen shot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdy8p.jpg) contains Simple text and audio text and where you can see 2 Text colors Blue and Black. Problem is to identify the Black color Text because it has some Simple Text and Audio Text and I want that Text into Excel in separate columns as displayed in Screen shot link above.

and i'm able to extract the text from Word document into Excel but problem is how can I identify Simple text and Audio text without changing the font style and color.

Any help in this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.